# Screenshots and Videos on cypress-reports

Tags: report, cypress

I'm trying to create a test report with screenshot and videos through cypress. the test reports are show but the screenshots and video are not . does anyone know how I can do that.
I used "cypress-mochawesome-reporter"
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-mochawesome-reporter

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can attach **screenshots** to the report. There is even an option to attach screenshots of every retry if you have a retry policy in the Cypress tests. To do that just follow the steps from the documentation. Pay attention for 2 points:

1. If in your tests you are overriding 'before:run' or 'after:run' you should add a separate piece of code from the documentation
2. Don't forget to add import to the cypress/support/e2e.js. Without it you will see no errors, but no screenshots will be attached to the report

> import 'cypress-mochawesome-reporter/register';

There is no possibility to attach a video for now. Mocha itself has only Test context. But in Cypress video is recorded as one file per Suite, not per test. That is why there is an open request to the Mocha to provide the Suite context to attach Cypress videos

https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome-report-generator/issues/150

Comment: With cypress 12, I can see the video!.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/LironEr/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/blob/master/examples/screenshots-folder/cypress.json)

In **cypress.json**

```
{
  "reporter": "cypress-mochawesome-reporter",
  "video": true,
  "screenshotsFolder": "images"
}
```

Comment: thanks for the Answer , but that makes no difference. the Screenshots and videos sind still not show .

Comment: [Video Embed Possible? #43](https://github.com/LironEr/cypress-mochawesome-reporter/issues/43) - ***Currently no***

Comment: Screenshots will work if you configure the correct folder.

Comment: how I can configure the correct folder ? cypress-mochawesome-reporter it doesn't give me any Infos where to store screenshotsFolder

Comment: The reporter has the option *embeddedScreenshots* that you can set in cypress.json: `"embeddedScreenshots": true`